# Putting together sklearn pipeline+nested cross-validation for KNN regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-selection, hyperparameters

I'm trying to figure out how to built a workflow for `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor` that includes:

- normalize features
- feature selection (best subset of 20 numeric features, no specific total)
- cross-validates hyperparameter K in range 1 to 20
- cross-validates model
- uses RMSE as error metric

There's so many different options in scikit-learn that I'm a bit overwhelmed trying to decide which classes I need.

Besides `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor`, I think I need:

```
sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline  
sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer
sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV
sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score

sklearn.feature_selection.selectKBest
OR
sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel
```

Would someone please show me what defining this pipeline/workflow might look like? I think it should be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV

# build regression pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([('normalize', Normalizer()),
                     ('kbest', SelectKBest(f_classif)),
                     ('regressor', KNeighborsRegressor())])

# try knn__n_neighbors from 1 to 20, and feature count from 1 to len(features)
parameters = {'kbest__k':  list(range(1, X.shape[1]+1)),
              'regressor__n_neighbors': list(range(1,21))}

# outer cross-validation on model, inner cross-validation on hyperparameters
scores = cross_val_score(GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10), 
                         X, y, cv=10, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", verbose=2)

rmses = np.abs(scores)**(1/2)
avg_rmse = np.mean(rmses)
print(avg_rmse)
```

It doesn't seem to error out, but a few of my concerns are:

- Did I perform the nested cross-validation properly so that my RMSE is unbiased?
- If I want the final model to be selected according to the best RMSE, am I supposed to use `scoring="neg_mean_squared_error"` for both `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV`?
- Is `SelectKBest, f_classif` the best option to use for selecting features for the `KNeighborsRegressor` model?
- How can I see:

  - which subset of features was selected as best
  - which K was selected as best

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code seems very okay. Also, the approach is correct to me. Do you get any error or unexpected result?

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. I updated my post with a little more information on my concerns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code seems okay.

For the `scoring="neg_mean_squared_error"` for both `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV`, I would do the same to make sure things run fine but the only way to test this is to remove the one of the two and see if the results change.

`SelectKBest` is a good approach but you can also use `SelectFromModel` or even other methods that you can find [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

Finally, in order to get the **best parameters** and the **features scores** I modified a bit your code as follows:

```
import ...


pipeline = Pipeline([('normalize', Normalizer()),
                     ('kbest', SelectKBest(f_classif)),
                     ('regressor', KNeighborsRegressor())])

# try knn__n_neighbors from 1 to 20, and feature count from 1 to len(features)
parameters = {'kbest__k':  list(range(1, X.shape[1]+1)),
              'regressor__n_neighbors': list(range(1,21))}

# changes here

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=10, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")

grid.fit(X, y)

# get the best parameters and the best estimator
print("the best estimator is \n {} ".format(grid.best_estimator_))
print("the best parameters are \n {}".format(grid.best_params_))

# get the features scores rounded in 2 decimals
pip_steps = grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['kbest']

features_scores = ['%.2f' % elem for elem in pip_steps.scores_ ]
print("the features scores are \n {}".format(features_scores))

feature_scores_pvalues = ['%.3f' % elem for elem in pip_steps.pvalues_]
print("the feature_pvalues is \n {} ".format(feature_scores_pvalues))

# create a tuple of feature names, scores and pvalues, name it "features_selected_tuple"

featurelist = ['age', 'weight']

features_selected_tuple=[(featurelist[i], features_scores[i], 
feature_scores_pvalues[i]) for i in pip_steps.get_support(indices=True)]

# Sort the tuple by score, in reverse order

features_selected_tuple = sorted(features_selected_tuple, key=lambda 
feature: float(feature[1]) , reverse=True)

# Print
print 'Selected Features, Scores, P-Values'
print features_selected_tuple
```

Results using my data:

```
the best estimator is
Pipeline(steps=[('normalize', Normalizer(copy=True, norm='l2')), ('kbest', SelectKBest(k=2, score_func=<function f_classif at 0x0000000004ABC898>)), ('regressor', KNeighborsRegressor(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
         metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=18, p=2,
         weights='uniform'))])

the best parameters are
{'kbest__k': 2, 'regressor__n_neighbors': 18}

the features scores are
['8.98', '8.80']

the feature_pvalues is
['0.000', '0.000']

Selected Features, Scores, P-Values
[('correlation', '8.98', '0.000'), ('gene', '8.80', '0.000')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that it shows the number of parameters used for `kbest__k`, but is there a way to see which columns were used specifically? Does `SelectKBest` just try the first column, then the first and second, etc., or does it try every permutation of # of features in the selected range?

Comment: @Jake I edited my post. I added the code for the features p values and scores. I think it is based on permutations as you said in your comment

Comment: @Jake Second update of my answer. now you can get the selected features

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it!

Comment: @Jake  glad that I could help

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but could you explain where did he/she perform the "nested" cross-validation step? I don't see it in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you use cross_val_score()?