# Feature selection: after or during nested cross-validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection, hyperparameters

I have managed to write some code doing a nested cross-validation using lightGBM as my regressor and wrapping everying with sklearn.pipeline.

Ultimately, I would now want to do feature selection (or really just get the features' importance for the final model) but I am wondering what is the best path to take from here. I guess there would be two possibilities:

1# Use this methodology to build a model (using .fit and .predict) using the best hyperparameters. Then check the importance of the features for this model.

2# Do feature selection in the inner fold of the nest cv but I am unsure how to do this exactly.

I guess #1 would be the easiest but I am unsure how to get the best hyperparamters for each outerfold.

This thread touches on it:
[Putting together sklearn pipeline+nested cross-validation for KNN regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150652/putting-together-sklearn-pipelinenested-cross-validation-for-knn-regression)

But the selected answers drops the cross_val_score altogether, meaning that it isn't nested cross-validation anymore (I would still like to perform the CV on the outer fold after getting the best hyperparameters on the inner fold).

So my **problem** is the following:

1. Can I get feature importances for each fold of the outer CV (I am
   aware that if I have 5 folds, I will get 5 different sets of feature
   importance)? And if yes, how?
2. Alternatively, should I just get the best hyperparameters for each
   fold (how?) and build a new model without CV on the whole dataset,
   based on these hyperparameters?

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, RandomizedSearchCV, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import scipy.stats as st

#Parameters for model building an reproducibility
X = X_age
y = y_age
RNGesus = 42 
state = 13
outer_scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error'
inner_scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error'

#### Nested CV with Random gridsearch ####

# Pipeline with standard scaling and the regressor    
regressors = [lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state = state)]
continuous_transformer = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler())])
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([('cont',continuous_transformer, continuous_variables)], remainder = 'passthrough')

for reg in regressors:
    steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('regressor', reg)]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

#inner and outer fold to be used
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=RNGesus)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=RNGesus)

#Hyperparameters of the regressor to be optimized using randomized search
params = {
'regressor__max_depth': (3, 5, 7, 10),
'regressor__lambda_l1': st.uniform(0, 5),
 'regressor__lambda_l2': st.uniform(0, 3)
}

#Pass the RandomizedSearchCV to cross_val_score

regression = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipeline, param_distributions = params, scoring=inner_scoring, cv=inner_cv, n_iter=200, verbose= 3, n_jobs= -1)
nested_score = cross_val_score(regression, X= X, y= y, cv = outer_cv, scoring=outer_scoring)

print('\n MAE for lightGBM model predicting age: %.3f' % (abs(nested_score.mean())))

print('\n'str(nested_score) + '<- outer CV')
```

**Edit**: Stated the problem clearly.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: is the feature selection process a stage in your pipeline?

Comment: @serafeim: I have added a clearer (I hope) formulation of the problem.


@ShaharA: Not currently. I just have a ```StandardScaler()``` and ```LGBMRegressor``` in it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered problems importing the `lightGBM` module so I coundn't run your code. But here is [a post](https://github.com/rosscleung/Projects/blob/b9abc20db545d9f483e90a9b046ea50c74f25718/Tutorial%20notebooks/Nested%20Cross%20Validation%20Example.ipynb) explaining how you cannot get the "winning" or optimal hyperparameters (as well as the `feature_importance_`) out of nested cross-validation by `cross_val_score`. Briefly, the reason is that `cross_val_score` only returns the measurement value.

1. Can I get feature importances for each fold of the outer CV (I am aware that if I have 5 folds, I will get 5 different sets of feature importance)? And if yes, how?

The answer is no with `cross_val_score`. But if you follow the code from that post, you'll be able to get the `feature_importance_` simply by `GSCV.best_estimator_.feature_importance_` under the for loop after `GSCV.fit()`.

2. Alternatively, should I just get the best hyperparameters for each fold (how?) and build a new model without CV on the whole dataset, based on these hyperparameters?

This is exactly what that post is talking about: getting you the "best" hyperparameters by nested cv. Ideally, you'll observe one combination of hyperparameters that wins all the time and that is the hyperparameters you'll use for the final model (with the entire training set). But when different "best" hyperparameter combinations appear during cv, there is no standard way to deal with it as far as I know.